# How can I solve my connection error in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I've tried to connect my db. All db settings in settings.py is checked and they are correct. When I run the server, I face an error which is shown below. I searched at internet and I find solutions but all them is working for lower python version. I am using the newest python version. My error is that:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
self.build_graph()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
if self.has_table():
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
return self._cursor()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
self.init_connection_state()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 231, in init_connection_state
if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 82, in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
cursor.execute('SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 146, in last_executed_query
query = query.decode(errors='replace')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: it looks like cursor.execute for some reason should have as parameter not an SQL query string, but rather same kind of query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old issue about previous versions of django. It is currently **3.1.2** and the code block which causes the problem was fixed.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py

You may try  `pip install -U django` if your django version is newer then 3.0.0 (good)

Other choices are changing your django versions source code at related line in your virtualenv (ugly), or monkey patch the related function (bad)